# MySQL code only gets executed once rather than multiple times in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['hasVoted']) && $_SESSION['hasVoted'] == '1') {
        print "You've already voted";
    }
else {
    if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
        $ID = $_SESSION['user']; // obtain the ID of the user from the login session
        var_dump($ID);
        $string_results = $_POST['h2'];
        $selected_radio = explode(',', $string_results);
        var_dump($selected_radio);
        $user_name = "root";
        $password = "";
        $database = "surveyTest";
        $server = "127.0.0.1";
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblquestions";
        $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
        $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
        if ($db_found) {
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);
            $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result); //return number of rows in the table
            var_dump($numRows);
            $qNum = 'q1';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++)
            {
                var_dump($qNum);
                $_SESSION['hasVoted'] = '1';
                $selected_Value = $selected_radio[$i];
                var_dump($selected_Value);
            //==================================================================================
            //  SET Multiple rows IN THE answers TABLE for each question for a given student.
            //==================================================================================
                $SQL = "INSERT INTO answers (QID, Answer, SID) VALUES ('$qNum', '$selected_Value', '$ID')";
                $result = mysql_query($SQL);
                    $question_Number = ltrim($qNum,'q');
                    $question_Number++;
                    $qNum ='q'.$question_Number;
            }
                mysql_close($db_handle);
                print "Thank you for participating!";
        }
        else {
        print "database error";
        }
    }

    else {
        header("location:login.php");;
    }
}
session_destroy();
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Process Survey</title>
</head>



<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When I execute the above code, the $SQL statement that consists of the INSERT only gets executed once. This means that it is only adding a single record to the database. However, I need it to add several records to the database which is equal to $numRows. The print out of $qNum and $selected_Value show the right thing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add a call to `mysql_error`, and see if the database is generating an error. You're also doing a lot of work to generate `$qNum` - doesn't it just have the value of `"q" . ($i + 1)`?

Comment: You should use mysqli_*, since mysql_* is depreciated

Comment: don't use multiple inserts, when you could build just one

Comment: Never trust user input! If you don't check user-supplied variables, you will get hacked after a few days (if you're lucky)...

Comment: How can I only use one statement?

Comment: the results are the output of radio buttons!!!

Comment: like so (`INSERT INTO answers (QID, Answer, SID) VALUES ('$qNum', '$selected_Value', '$ID'),('$qNum', '$selected_Value', '$ID'),('$qNum', '$selected_Value', '$ID'),('$qNum', '$selected_Value', '$ID')`

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Do **NOT** use this code (even after you fix the problem). All of your DB operations are simply assuming success as well. Never assume success. Always assume failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try again using `$result = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());`

also are the Primary keys ok on your table?

Comment: Thanks for this, this is one thing that I missed. So, to find out the error is it just echo mysql_errno($db_handle)

Comment: mysql_error, not mysql_errno which will not give you as useful information.

Comment: no just the above code and PHP will print out any faults you might have.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to work correctly you would have to have the same number in your `$numRows` variable, which is based on your `$result` variable, as you do in `count($selected_radio)`, which is probably not the case. I'm also concerned that you may not have an HTML `<input type='radio' value='whatever' name='h2' />`. Why would this be a comma separated String? A radio button should only return the value which is `'checked'`. Anyways, maybe you have `name='h2'`, in a hidden input or something. In this case your loop should look something like:

```
for($i=0,$l=count($selected_radio); $i<$l; $i++){
  //your code in here
}
```

If I was you I would use a Library like **PHPglue** to handle your Sticky Form issues. Visit https://www.PHPglue.com for more details.

Comment: In my case, h2 is a hidden input type.